# Using raw MYSQL queries in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm working with symfony but instead of using doctrine i use raw mysql queries.

```
$query1 = "SELECT sport_id FROM coach WHERE id = $id";
$statement1 = $connection->query($query1);
$statement1->execute();
$sport_id = $statement1->fetch();
```

For the above query it gives an error as "Notice: Array to string conversion
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException"

can someone please explain what is wrong with this? I'm beginner in symfony

Comment: Your $id variable seem to be an array, not a string. Aso please use prepared/parameterized queries, to safe guard from sql injection. http://mossco.co.uk/symfony-2/how-to-use-raw-sql-queries-in-symfony-2/

Comment: you can use a DQL doctrine langague for write SQL in the same appareance than your SQL native.

Comment: Use `$sport_id=$statement1->getSingleScalarResult();`